# After Magmi import of price changes, special price displays?

Tags: magento, magmi

After I import products with a change to pricing via Magmi, I get the 'Now Only' with the new price display along with the old price. I am updating the price only so I have no idea why 'Now Only' should suddenly start displaying. If I do a hard save on any of the effected products via Magento admin, the pricing no longer displays. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your datasource file?  Are you including the `special_price` column in your datasource?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?